# CoreData extension: insert NSManagedObject in NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Usually, when I need to insert a new object into the CoreData's `NSManagedObjectContext`, I have to do it in the following manner:

```
        let device = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Device", into: context) as! Device
        device. .....// call methods on "device"
```

However, it makes the process error-prone since the return type of the `.insertNewObject(forEntityName:` is not type-safe and requires a forced cast. Also, the `entityName` parameter won't be fetched if the class will be refactored, making it a potential source of runtime errors which are really hard to trace.

I'm interested in using a more type-safe approach that would minimize the risk of programmer's error, e.g. by introducing the following extension for the whole Swift module:

```
import CoreData

extension NSManagedObject {
    class func insert(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {
        return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: String(describing: self), into: context) as! Self
    }
}
```

After introducing this extension, the code at the call site looks as follows:

```
        let device = Device.insert(in: context)
        device. .....// call methods on "device"
```

If the `Device` class is renamed, the method parameter `entityName` will be also changed accordingly.

**Are there any potential limitations of this approach?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use

```
let device = Device(context: context)
```

Which was added in iOS10 for this exact reason?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apparently, the app I work on has a minimum supported version of iOS 9. The proper solution is to increase the supported version.